# Phase correlation - wrong angle of rotation

Tags: opencv, detection, object-detection

I am trying to find the angle between two simple images of ellipses:

[image]

[image]

The relative angle is about 20 degrees.

The logPolar images are (for scale magnitude = 10)

[image]

[image]

But openCV function phaseCorrelate() gives the wrong result: 72.9

Here is the code:

```
    cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread("ellipse1.png");
    cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread("ellipse2.png");

    cv::cvtColor(image1, image1, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cv::cvtColor(image2, image2, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    cv::Mat logImage1 = cv::Mat::zeros(image1.size(), CV_8UC1);
    cv::Mat logImage2 = cv::Mat::zeros(image2.size(), CV_8UC1);

    double magnitude = 10;
    cv::logPolar(image1, logImage1, cv::Point2f(image1.cols / 2.0, image1.rows / 2.0), magnitude, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    cv::logPolar(image2, logImage2, cv::Point2f(image2.cols / 2.0, image2.rows / 2.0), magnitude, cv::INTER_CUBIC);


    logImage1.convertTo(logImage1, CV_64F);
    logImage2.convertTo(logImage2, CV_64F);

    cv::Point2d rotScale = cv::phaseCorrelate(logImage1, logImage2);

    double rotation = rotScale.y * 180 / (logImage2.cols >> 1);
    double scale = exp(rotScale.x / magnitude);
```

So, the result in rotation is 72.9 instead of ~20 degrees.

What am I doing wrong? Or am I ignoring something important?
Also, there is a parameter "scale magnitude" in the logPolar() function, which strongly affects the results of the rotation angle evaluation. Is there any possibility to estimate a "good" value of this parameter?

I suppose that the result is wrong because phaseCorrelate() function extracts the wrong peak in Fourier domain.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it actually 20 degrees or 17.1? Because if it's 90 - the angle you're getting, it might be something simple like a mixed up x, y or a shift in frequency space.

Comment: @Alexander Reynolds, I thought so, actually I dont know the exact angle. But the results looks unreliable, because change in magnitude inevitably leade, for example, to the result angle = 110.